# Выделение текста курсором с последующей манипуляцией над выделенным блоком

Tags: текст, мышь, курсор

Буду признателен, если подскажите как реализовать (ну или хотя бы в каком направлении мне двигаться) чтобы реализовать "Выделение текста курсором с последующей манипуляцией над выделенным блоком".

Т.е. представьте себе блок текста. Пользователь по-своему желанию выделяет часть текста курсором мышки. Сайт должен каким-то образом определить, что (точнее какой) кусок был выделен. Далее выделенный блок текста можно, например, положить в переменную. Я не могу понять как научить сайт определять что было выделено. Какой язык использовать.

Answer (score 1):

**JavaScript** Используйте метод window **getSelection** (в IE8 и ниже не работает)

```
var selectedText=window.getSelection().toString();
```

это будет выделенный текст без тегов